# Tamanho da tela JPanel

Tags: java, swing

Eu havia criado um JPanel com uma tela com um bom tamanho.
Depois tive que trocar meu monitor com uma resolução menor.

Agora o tamanho da tela do JPanel está pequena, fazendo que parte do visual que eu coloquei não apareça. Já tentei diminuir a resolução, o tamanho do painel, criar barra de rolagem e nada.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você poderia editar a pergunta para postar o seu código? Não dá para saber o que poderíamos mexer no seu código se você não colocá-lo na sua pergunta. Se possível um código compilável para que possamos facilmente fazer experimentos e testes com ele.

Comment: Experimente deixar os componentes do seu JPanel redimensionáveis. Usando o NetBeans, você pode setar isso pelo painel propriedades do componente, em Layout. Caso não resolva, poste detalhes do código aqui.